# How should I make and use a method for changing the camera(transform) position and angle at run time from any script/s?

Tags: unity, c#

The script is attached to a Camera.  A bit messed but it's working.

For changing the camera height at run time I'm using a variable name cameraHeight at this line number 88:

```
Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, cameraHeight, -distanceFromTarget);
```

The original line was :

```
Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distanceFromTarget);
```

but if instead, I want to create a public method something like :

```
public void ChangeCameraAngle()
{

}
```

What should I do inside this method and then how to use it for things like changing the camera(transform) height or angle in run time?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform targetToRotateAround;

    public bool saveDuringPlay = false;

    public float distanceFromTarget = 5.0f;
    private float oldDistanceFromTarget;

    public float xSpeed = 120.0f;
    public float ySpeed = 120.0f;
    private float oldxSpeed, oldySpeed;

    public float yMinLimit = -20f;
    public float yMaxLimit = 80f;
    private float oldyMinLimit, oldyMaxLimit;

    public float distanceMin = .5f;
    public float distanceMax = 15f;
    private float oldDistanceMin, oldDistanceMax;

    public float cameraHeight;
    private float oldCameraHeight;

    public bool makeTransition = false;

    private Rigidbody rigidbody;
    private float x = 0.0f;
    private float y = 0.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
        x = angles.y;
        y = angles.x;

        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        // Make the rigid body not change rotation
        if (rigidbody != null)
        {
            rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
        }

        LoadSettings();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (saveDuringPlay)
        {
            SaveDuringPlay();

            oldDistanceFromTarget = distanceFromTarget;
            oldxSpeed = xSpeed;
            oldySpeed = ySpeed;
            oldyMinLimit = yMinLimit;
            oldyMaxLimit = yMaxLimit;
            oldDistanceMin = distanceMin;
            oldDistanceMax = distanceMax;
            oldCameraHeight = cameraHeight;
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (targetToRotateAround)
        {
            x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * distanceFromTarget * 0.02f;
            y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;

            y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);

            distanceFromTarget = Mathf.Clamp(distanceFromTarget - Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * 5, distanceMin, distanceMax);

            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Linecast(targetToRotateAround.position, transform.position, out hit))
            {
                distanceFromTarget -= hit.distance;
            }
            Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, cameraHeight, -distanceFromTarget);
            Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + targetToRotateAround.position;

            transform.rotation = rotation;
            transform.position = position;
        }
    }

    public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360F)
            angle += 360F;
        if (angle > 360F)
            angle -= 360F;
        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }

    public void SaveDuringPlay()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("DistanceFromTarget", distanceFromTarget);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("xSpeed", xSpeed);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("ySpeed", ySpeed);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("yMinLimit", yMinLimit);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("yMaxLimit", yMaxLimit);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("DistanceMin", distanceMin);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("DistanceMax", distanceMax);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("CameraHeight", cameraHeight);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MakeTransition", boolToInt(makeTransition));
    }

    public void LoadSettings()
    {
        distanceFromTarget = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("DistanceFromTarget");
        oldDistanceFromTarget = distanceFromTarget;

        xSpeed = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("xSpeed");
        oldxSpeed = xSpeed;
        ySpeed = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("ySpeed");
        oldySpeed = xSpeed;

        yMinLimit = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("yMinLimit");
        oldyMinLimit = yMinLimit;
        yMaxLimit = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("yMaxLimit");
        oldyMaxLimit = yMaxLimit;

        distanceMin = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("DistanceMin");
        oldDistanceMin = distanceMin;
        distanceMax = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("DistanceMax");
        oldDistanceMax = distanceMax;

        cameraHeight = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("CameraHeight");
        oldCameraHeight = cameraHeight;

        makeTransition = intToBool(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MakeTransition", 0));
    }

    int boolToInt(bool val)
    {
        if (val)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    bool intToBool(int val)
    {
        if (val != 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To lift any object up or down you can simply add *Vector3.up* to your position:

```
transform.position = transform.position + Vector3.up*myDistance;   //if myDistance is negative it will go down
// or even more simpler:
transform.Translate(Vector3.up*myDistance); // does exactly the same job
```

(*In general: to move object to some direction just find that direction vector and add to your position. In this case direction vector is Vector3.up*).

To rotate object around by some angle you can simply use Rotate:

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up,myAngle);
```

This will instantly lift/rotate object to desired height/angle.

Comment: what about the method ChangeCameraAngle()? Should I create and use that one so I can make changes from other scripts?

Comment: I see no wrong in doing that

Comment: If answer is correct/helpful you can accept it